# jQuery - selecting all the text in an input field closes the form

Tags: jquery, html, mouse

Sorry for the title; I don't even really know how to explain this issue, but I'll try my best.

I have a form that is inside a div that appears with a darkened background when a linked is clicked. A good example are jQuery image galleries, that when an image thumbnail is clicked, there is a semi-transparent div that covers the whole page with a slightly smaller div inside displaying a larger version of the image. See this for a demo: http://themeforest.net/item/ztudio-responsive-portfolio-blog/full_screen_preview/4716505?ref=1stwebdesigner

The only difference between the referenced URL and what I have is that I have a form instead of a zoomed-in image.

Anyway, my problem is this: if the user enters the wrong data in an input field, and then uses the mouse to select all the text, the div closes if the mouse is dragged off the div.

I believe the problem is being caused by this function:

```
$(document).on('mouseup', function (e) {
    if ($('#log-in').has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $('#log-in').fadeOut(200);
        $('#aLogin').show();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="fade_bg" id="log-in">
    <div class="actionDiv">
        <span class="errForm" id="loginError"></span>
        <form id="login_form" action="./classes/login/Authenticator.php" method="post">
            <p>username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></p>
            <p>password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="adminLogin" value="Log in" id="adminLogin" /></p>
        </form>
        <p><a id="cancelLogin" href="">Cancel</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#log-in {
    display: none;
}
```

I don't know how to modify the jQuery so that the div closes only if the user explicitly clicks outside the div containing the form. Any ideas?

Comment: could you also show the HTML ?. My idea is that you remove this line and add a `click` event for the transparent overlay.

Comment: Added HTML and CSS :>

Comment: @Spokey that's exactly what I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this (replacing mouseover on document by click) :

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ($('#log-in').has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $('#log-in').fadeOut(200);
        $('#aLogin').show();
    }
});
```

But it's hard to be sure if it's good without seeing the HTML too

Comment: Thanks. I just added the HTML and bit of CSS I used.

Comment: Yes. I just changed `$(document)` to `$('.fade_bg')` and it seems to have done the trick. I just wanted to be sure that it wouldn't close if I clicked on the inner div containing the form. Thank you!

Comment: Read the jQuery documentation on mouseup http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/ , it may shed some light on the behaviour of events.